# Android: How to make the margin of a button relative to screen width?

Tags: java, android, xml

for example I want the button's margin to be 1/4 of the screen width (in pixels), what should I do? I prefer to change something in layout xml file instead of coding.

Comment: can you do this in xml with `layout_weight`?

Comment: Can't you simply use a linaer layout with `layout_weight` and empty columns to the left and right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4" >

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>

<Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
    />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You actually don't need the extra views. weightSum takes care of that

Answer (score 0):

Use `weightSum` and `layout_weight` to achieve this.

For e.g

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:visibility="visible" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="testing" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Here 25(button) is 1/4th of 100(linearlayout). It is just an idea. You will have to adapt it for your requirement.

Comment: But I want the `margin` to be relative, not the size of the button

Comment: Add blank views. And set their sizes, instead of Button.